# Deploy Mongodb on kubernetes in replicaset Mode

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kind

I am trying depoly a replicaset of mongodb in my kind kubernetes.

Well, my first step is run thsi command:

```
helm upgrade --install mongodb bitnami/mongodb 
--set mongodb.global.storageClass=standard
--set mongodbRootPassword=root 
--set mongodbUsername=mongoUser 
--set mongodbPassword=mongoUser 
--set mongodbDatabase=articles 
--set mongodb.persistence.size=5Gi 
--set mongodb.service.type=NodePort 
--set mongodb.service.nodePort=30005 
--set mongodb.metrics.enabled=false 
--set replicaSet.enabled=true
--namespace replicaset-data
```

But I have tow questions:

- How I can connect to this replicaSet?
- The next question is about the persistent data. Y have a extraMounts defined y my kind kulster, but I not found the way to use it in this helm

Could anyone help my in this?

A lot of Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> How I can connect to this replicaSet?

You can use the K8s service to connect with these replicas [service type like LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), [Port-forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/), using ingress

> The next question is about the persistent data. Y have a extraMounts
> defined y my kind kulster, but I not found the way to use it in this
> helm

You can use the **PV** and **PVC** with the K8s cluster to persist the data of your database.

Read more at : https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/3291

Prameters : https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/mongodb#persistence-parameters

Comment: ok, I can use the extramount using pv and pvc... so, this cuestion is solved. However... I still not achieve the point of connect to the replicaset outside the k8s cluster. I am still researching...
Thanks!

Comment: You can use service type as load balancer to expose the cluster of Mongo to external .

Comment: For white listing you can use ip white listing range in service it’s type load balancer.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/

Comment: If above answers resolve your answer feel free to mark it as answer or do upvote if found it helpful.

Comment: Ok... is a good way but not that I need. I want to do the access throw a ingress.... using as ingress controller Traefik

Comment: Feel free to post new question requirement and details tht have implemented and facing error. While you can update status of this question if you it’s resolves your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well.
I have finally a response for the questions... is not a definedly respose, but is a progress.

All that I says here, is about binami/monogdb Helm Clart.

Firstly, I thinks is better usea a values.yaml for deploy the helm; so, you can see all the available parameters for the helm. Here, you can see that if you deploy the helm in standalone mode, you can indicate the name of the PVC, so, yo can bindind your deployment with your pvc.
However, you can see in the values.yaml, that in replicaset mode,  you can't set this parameter (you can set anothers like the space, type...).

By other hand, the url for conect to mongo, insde the kubernetes cluster is:

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@<service-name>.<namespace>:<port>/?authMechanism=DEFAULT&directConnection=true
```

If you deploy mongo on standalone mode, the  is by default "mongodb". If you deploy mongo on replicaset mode, the  is by default "mongodb-headless".

So, knowing that, is easy set your environment variable in your cliente service for connect to mongo service.

So, the remain answer is ¿is a way to set the pvc in a replicaset mode? ¿how?